# Inconstant Overheating Issue in Laptop

Tags: laptop, cooling, overheating

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 with 960m VGA. You may have heard about the cooling problems . So just after I bought it , I bought a cooling pad too. 
not the best possible one, but it keeps CPU's temp around 78 c , and GPU's around 70 , under load. that was enough for me. The problem is that without no noticeable change in my situation(room temp, cooling pad setting, ... ) temp sometimes gets out of control and goes up to around 90 - 95 under load. It's how it is for some time(few days i mean) and after that for some time it is OK . and the loop goes on. I've experienced the whole procedure two times.

I cant figure out what is causing this!

Comment: First thought is to check any fans. Are they failing then recovering? Or a thermostat for the fan? Or the bios/OS settings for when the fans should operate?

Comment: how should I check the fans?

Comment: You could go into the BIOS screen prior to boot up (DEL or F1 key when computer starts). This will show if you have any monitored fans and the speed.... But how are you monitoring CPU temp, etc? Doesn't this software show fans spin speed?

Comment: Sounds like dust build up is a possibility.  Buy a couple cans of compressed air and open your computer up.  Blow out all the dust.  Sometimes you have to remove the cpu fan and scrap the dust out.

Comment: @cybernard , i've recently bought the laptop and im sure there is no dust accumulation. also it works as it must do most of the time.

Comment: @Kram , i couldn't find anything fan-related in my bios setting. i installed speedfan on my computer and its also not monitoring my fan situation.

Comment: Speedfan is not very good on modern computers - try [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) instead.

Comment: @harrymc And how is that supposed to help me? i need fans' data :(

Comment: Speccy does all of it.

Comment: @harrymc , So could you please tell me where can i find it? As far as I saw, it only shows some temperatures and some clocks and some other stuff related to main hardware pieces.

Comment: It shows all heat sensors and I trust it more than Speedfan. Speedfan totally failed on my latest computer. You can find it in my link above.

Comment: @harrymc , just to make sure we're talking about the same thing : i need fans spinning data (RPM) . I have speccy . It simply doesn't have anything related to fan! I meant which part of the app in my last comment.

Comment: You have not mentioned RPM in your question, but why would you need RPM when the problem is temperature. Note: Your running temperatures are extremely high and should be improved - CPU at 78c is unacceptable, it should be less than 50. Question: Have you used the Task Manager to find some correlation between CPU usage and running tasks when a spike happens? Have you cleaned all air passages? If there is no explanation and the computer is still under warranty, I would call Lenovo Support.

Comment: under 50? its a laptop! even surface temperature under load is near 60! have a look at [this](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-Y50-70-GTX-960M-4K-Notebook-Review.145340.0.html) . also in the first comment someone told me to check fans performance, and i said speedfan was not working and then you told me to use speccy. that's why I want RPM. tnx.

Comment: I have seen a laptop heat up while running a full virus scan, which didn't show up in the list of processes.

Comment: Nevertheless, your laptop has a heat problem, see for example [this thread](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-2360088/normal-laptop-temperatures.html).

Comment: @harrymc, Maybe I should've bought another laptop, but that's not something i can think about now! all I cant understand is why it doesn't act the same in the same situations.

Comment: Perhaps a better cooling pad will improve the situation. Assure also that all air passages are clean. If your environment is dusty, cleaning the interior might help. If the computer is still under warranty, call Lenovo Support or the shop you bought it from. If it is not, then a repairman might verify the thermal paste of the CPU or replace the CPU cooling fan by a better one. I have also seen drastic solutions involving making holes in laptop casings, but I don't recommend such "solutions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CPU is too hot, while the GPU has more normal temperatures.
It is clear that there is a problem with the cooling of the CPU on your
computer. I have no idea if this problem is common to your computer model
or is specific to your computer.

Things you can try :

- A better cooling pad may improve the situation
- Assure that all air passages are clean
- If your environment is dusty, cleaning the interior might help
- If the computer is still under warranty, call Lenovo Support or the shop you bought it from
- If it is not, then a repairman might verify the thermal paste of the CPU or replace the CPU cooling fan by a better one

Comment: well, I'm saying again, when surface temperatures reach 59 c , It's really normal for cpu to be around 80 ! it's hot , I know but i think there is no problem with this specific unit. I took it to the support actually just a weak after i bought it, someone opened it up, checked some parts and told me there is no problem with it! I dunno what else could I have done. anyway , thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't know how long ago that was, but there are laptop models that simply run hot by construction. You could maybe avoid over-heating via software (in addition to hardware measures). See [articel1](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Lenovo-Y50-70-temperature-problem/td-p/1738457) for the ''Energy Manager'' and [article2](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2297457/lenovo-y50-cpu-throttling-issue.html) for [ThrottleStop](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2288/throttlestop-6-00/) (be very careful with the last one).

Comment: I installed the Throttlestop app and lowered the multiplier from 26 to 10 while gaming. It had a significant effect and now my CPU doesn't pass 72-73 without ruining my gaming experience even a bit! Thanks for suggesting it! BTW, will this kind of underclocking damage the processor in a long-time scale? ( actually because you mentioned to be careful using it ! )

Comment: I mentioned that because of the warnings on the ThrottleStop page. As you did survey your CPU temperature and don't experience weird power problems for exceeding your PSU, you are "probably" OK .

Answer (score 0):

This has basically already been said, but I had serious overheating issues on my Dell laptop, and it was simply a dirty fan. I found out that the majority of overheating issues are due to a dirty fan. I used a youtube video specific to my laptop model to take it apart and clean it myself. No issues now and I felt like a rockstar doing it myself! ;-)